# How to download a spreadsheet using remix run

Tags: remix.run

I am trying to prompt the user to download a spreadhsheet using remix run.  I have the spreadsheet being created correctly and it writes it to a disk if I want.  But what I actually want it the user to be prompted with a download option they can save to their computer.

In theoru the header Content-Disposition should trigger a download but it doesnt?

```
    const spreadsheet = exportToSpreadsheet(tableData, ticksheet.headings.map(h => ({ id: h.id, title: h.name })));

        console.log(spreadsheet)
        
        return new Response(spreadsheet, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename="ticksheet-${ticksheetId}.xlsx"`
            },
        });
```

and this is my export to spreadsheet function

```
export function exportToSpreadsheet(data, headings) {
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();

    const columnHeadings = Object.keys(data[0]);

    columnHeadings.forEach(heading => {
        const columnData = data.map(row => ({ [heading]: row[heading] }));

        let sheetTitle = heading;
        if (sheetTitle.length > 31) {
            sheetTitle = sheetTitle.substring(0, 31);
        }

        const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(columnData);

        worksheet['!cols'] = [{ wch: 20 }];

        XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, sheetTitle);
    });

    const buffer = XLSX.write(workbook, { type: 'buffer', bookType: 'xlsx' });

    return buffer;
```